# Смысл сообщения WM_NULL

Tags: windows, winapi

Какой смысл в постинге этого сообщения окнам Windows?

Comment: http://www.ucosoft.com/what-is-the-usage-of-wm_null.html

Comment: Спасибо, @Котик_хочет_кушать.

Comment: Одна из главных задач - проверить что очередь сообщений окна "живая", не подвисшая... Если в течении заданного вами интервала (метод SendMessageTimeout) система вернула 0 - очередь живая, иначе - "Хьюстон, у нас проблемы" :)

Answer (score 1):

Иногда, при потере фокуса, всплывающее меню в System Tray при потере фокуса не закрывается. Поэтому, при обработке сообщений для всплывающего меню необходимо поместить окно на передний план и послать ему сообщение WM_NULL.

Comment: Приложение отправляет сообщение WM_NULL, если оно желает посылать сообщение, которое окно получатель должно проигнорировать.

Comment: Спасибо конечно же за практический пример. Это только в плюс. Насчет того, что данный мэседж игнорится получателем, мне известно...но если сообщение НИКАК не обрабатывается, то и смысл от него? Ведь всплывающему меню можно послать и другое сообщение, которое выведет его в топ всех окон Windows, например, это сделает одна из многих функций "активации" окна( SetForeground, например )...

Answer (score 1):

WM_NULL часто используется в хуках, когда "отменить" сообщение нельзя, можно его только **изменить**,

вот, чтобы измененное сообщение не нашло своего адресата в иерархии обработчиков окна, его и помечают WM_NULL